# Proving the intersection of two sets is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Two sets of real numbers A and B.  A is bounded above, B is bounded below.  Prove their intersection is bounded.

I understand that the union of the two sets A and B would be bounded but I can't necessarily see how the intersection is bounded.  How do we know that their intersection is not the empty set?

Comment: Why would you think the union was bounded?  If $A$ are the reals $≤0$ and $B$ are the reals $≥0$ then the union is the entire line.

Comment: To your final question, I expect you are to regard the empty set as bounded.  You are certainly correct that we might have $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you lulu for that example.

Comment: The empty set is, of course, bounded. See the properties section of this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The empty set is bounded: $\forall x \in \emptyset : (x \le 1) \land (x \ge -1)$ is certainly a (vacuusly) true statement.
- The union of two such sets need not be bounded: Take $A = (-\infty, 1]$, $B= [-1,\infty)$, then $A \cup B= \mathbb{R}$ but $A \cap B = [-1,1]$.
- To see the statement: let $a_0$ be an upperbound for $A$ and $b_0$ a lower bound for $B$. Let $x \in A \cap B$ be arbitrary. Then $x \in A$ so $x \le a_0$ an  $x\in B$ too, so $b_0 \le x$. So $A \cap B \subseteq [a_0, b_0]$ hence $A \cap B$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This cleared up my confusion VERY well.  I greatly appreciate the explanation.